# How to make a dijit/editor manualy resizable?

Tags: javascript, dojo, editor, resizable

I am trying to make a rich text editor situated in a dialog box, manually re-sizable(with mouse).  Is there any dojo widget to bring it about?

Here is my code:

```html
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog" data-dojo-id="myFormDialog" title="Editor">
  <div class="dijitDialogPaneContentArea" data-dojo-attach-point="name">
    <label id="editorLabel" for="name"><b>Insert your explanation below: </b></label>
    <input id="editorInput" type="hidden" name="editorContent" data-dojo-attach-point="name" style="display:none" />
    <div id="editorContent" dojoType="dijit/Editor" height="200px" extraPlugins=" ['createLink', 'unlink', 'insertImage'] "></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="editorButton" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button" iconClass="dijitNoIcon" onclick="myFormDialog.show()" height="">Show Editor</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following CSS, which enforce `resize` on your `textarea`.

```
textarea {
    resize: both !important;
}
```

Live Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/esrcju2p/7/

You can read more about `resize` property here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp

---

```
require(["dijit/form/Textarea", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Textarea){
    var textarea = new Textarea({
    style: "resize:both",
        name: "myarea",
        value: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.",
        style: "width:200px;"
    }, "myarea").startup();
});
```

---

---

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a dojo widget but adding this line in css file worked like a charm:

```
.claro .dijitEditorIFrame{ resize:both; }
```